# How to add strings to items in list that resulted from split?

Tags: python, string, list, split

I am building a function that accepts a string as input, splits it based on certain separator and ends on period. Essentially what I need to do is add certain pig latin words onto certain words within the string if they fit the criteria.

The criteria are:

> if the word    starts  with    a   non-letter  or  contains    no  characters, do  nothing to  it
>
> if the word    starts  with    a   vowel,  add 'way' to    the end
>
> if the word    starts  with    a   consonant,  place   the first   letter  at  the end and add 'ay'

For output example:

> simple_pig_latin("i    like    this") → 'iway  ikelay histay.'
>   --default sep(space) and    end(dot)
>
> simple_pig_latin("i    like    this", sep='.') → 'i    like    thisway.'
>   --separator is  dot, so whole   thing   is  a   single  “word”
>
> simple_pig_latin("i.like.this",sep='.',end='!') → 'iway.ikelay.histay!'
>   --sep   is  '.' and end is  '!'
>
> simple_pig_latin(".") → '..'
>   --only  word    is  '.',    so  do  nothing to  it  and add a   '.' to  the end

It is now:

```
def simple_pig_latin(input, sep='', end='.'):
    words=input.split(sep)
    new_sentence=""
    Vowels= ('a','e','i','o','u')
    Digit= (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    cons=('b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z')
    for word in words:
        if word[0] in Vowels:
            new_word= word+"way"

        if word[0] in Digit:
            new_word= word

        if word[0] in cons:
            new_word= word+"ay"

        else:
            new_word= word

        new_sentence= new_sentence + new_word+ sep

    new_sentence= new_sentence.strip(sep) + sentenceEndPunctuation
    return new_sentence
```

Example error:

```
ERROR: test_simple_pig_latin_8 (__main__.AllTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testerl8.py", line 125, in test_simple_pig_latin_8
result = simple_pig_latin(input,sep='l',end='')
File "/Users/kgreenwo/Desktop/student.py", line 8, in simple_pig_latin
if word[0] in Vowels:
```

IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to as string and what as "items".
I am also not sure what `[i][0]` is for as it has nothing written prior to it.

Comment: Just FYI, 'histay' is not pig latin for 'this'.  Since  th acts as a single letter, it is 'isthay' (pronounced 'is' (rhyme with 'hiss') -'thay' (starts like 'thing' but ryhmes with 'say').  Your logic will need to accommodate nuances like this...

Comment: regarding your code, the issue is that variable `end` appears unused and you never add the punctuation (or strip it out, depending on what your intent is..)

Comment: FYI, you should also include your "test code" that actually produces the error, including the contents of any data you pass to it (like a file, etc).

Comment: @SurestTexas I am simply following my assignment instructions. I am not actually designing program for pig latin.

Comment: Hopefully the test for your assignment does not require you to correctly implement it...

Comment: @SurestTexas it does not, so all is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the means of adding strings together correct: you use the `+` operator, as you have in `new_string = new_string + "way"`.

You have two other major issues, however:

1. To determine whether a variable can be found in a list (in your case, a tuple), you’d probably want to use the `in` operator. Instead of `if [i][0]==Vowels:` you would use `if [i][0] in Vowels:`.
2. When you reconstruct the string with the new words, you will need to add the *word* to your `new_string`. Instead of `new_string=new_string+"way"` you might use `new_string = new_string+word+"way"`. If you choose to do it this way, you’ll also need to decide when to add the `sep` back to each word.

Another way of joining smaller strings into larger ones with a known separator is to create a list of the new individual strings, and then join the strings back together using your known separator:

```
separator = ' '
words = sentence.split(separator)
newWords = []
for word in words:
    newWord = doSomething(word)
    newWords.append(newWord)

newSentence = separator.join(newWords)
```

In this way, you don’t have to worry about either the first or last word not needing a separator.

In your case, `doSomething` might look like:

```
def doSomething(word):
    if word[0] in Vowels:
        return word + "way"
    elif word[0] in Consonants:
        return word + "ay"
     #and so forth
```

### How to write a function

On a more basic level, you will probably find it easier to create your functions in steps, rather than trying to write everything at once. At each step, you can be sure that the function (or script) works, and then move on to the next step. For example, your first version might be as simple as:

```
def simple_pig_latin(sentence, separator=' '):
    words = sentence.split(separator)
    for word in words:
        print word

simple_pig_latin("i like this")
```

This does nothing except print each word in the sentence, one per line, to show you that the function is breaking the sentence apart into words the way that you expect it to be doing. Since words are fundamental to your function, you need to be certain that you have words and that you know where they are before you can continue. Your error of trying to check [i][0] would have been caught much more easily in this version, for example.

A second version might then do nothing except return the sentence recreated, taking it apart and then putting it back together the same way it arrived:

```
def simple_pig_latin(sentence, separator=' '):
    words = sentence.split(separator)
    new_sentence = ""
    for word in words:
        new_sentence = new_sentence + word + separator

    return new_sentence

print simple_pig_latin("i like this")
```

Your third version might try to add the end punctuation:

```
def simple_pig_latin(sentence, separator=' ', sentenceEndPunctuation='.'):
    words = sentence.split(separator)
    new_sentence = ""
    for word in words:
        new_sentence = new_sentence + word + separator

    new_sentence = new_sentence + sentenceEndPunctuation

    return new_sentence

print simple_pig_latin("i like this")
```

At this point, you’ll realize that there’s an issue with the separator getting added on in front of the end punctuation, so you might fix that by stripping off the separator when done, or by using a list to construct the new_sentence, or any number of ways.

```
def simple_pig_latin(sentence, separator=' ', sentenceEndPunctuation='.'):
    words = sentence.split(separator)
    new_sentence = ""
    for word in words:
        new_sentence = new_sentence + word + separator

    new_sentence = new_sentence.strip(separator) + sentenceEndPunctuation

    return new_sentence

print simple_pig_latin("i like this")
```

Only when you can return the new sentence without the pig latin endings, and understand how that works, would you add the pig latin to your function. And when you add the pig latin, you would do it one rule at a time:

```
def simple_pig_latin(sentence, separator=' ', sentenceEndPunctuation='.'):
    vowels= ('a','e','i','o','u')
    words = sentence.split(separator)
    new_sentence = ""
    for word in words:
        if word[0] in vowels:
            new_word = word + "way"
        else:
            new_word = word

        new_sentence = new_sentence + new_word + separator

    new_sentence = new_sentence.strip(separator) + sentenceEndPunctuation

    return new_sentence

print simple_pig_latin("i like this")
```

And so on, adding each change one at a time, until the function performs the way you expect.

When you try to build the function complete all at once, you end up with competing errors that make it difficult to see where the function is going wrong. By building the function one step at a time, you should generally only have one error at a time to debug.

Comment: what do you mean by do something? I'm not seeing how this connects with my if else statements.

Comment: "doSomething" is a stand-in for a function that will do something with "word".

Comment: I'm confused. I've adjusted my code. See above edited code and maybe you can explain further? I just want one function.

Comment: For the moment, ignore everything after "another way". Then read item two again. Instead of return (which ends the function) use new_string = new_string + word + "way" (or whatever the appropriate ending is). And initialize new_string as "" (an empty string) instead of [] (an empty list).

Comment: I did. I adjusted and I'm still failing all test cases. I've provided an example of test fail error in above question.

Comment: I added some advice on building a function up step by step. You’ll want to test your function on your own, in stages, before you submit the finished function for external testing.

Comment: I'm getting an out of range error now that I've correct all the code. Thank you for your input. You are certainly correct it would be easier that way. I'll work on that. Why am I getting out of range error? I used code listed above and the input was:         def test_simple_pig_latin_8(self):
  input = "hello world"
  expected = 'ehayllo worwaylday'
  result = simple_pig_latin(input,sep='l',end='')
  self.assertEqual(result, expected)

Comment: You'll notice that the out of range error occurs on line 8, in which you’re looking for the first character in string “word”. My guess is that “word” is empty, and has no first character. If there exists the possibility that “word” will sometimes have no characters in it (for example, double spaces are allowed in your sentences) you’ll need to decide how to handle those situations. You could remove all double spaces (using `input.replace("  ", " ")` before splitting `input`) or you could preserve them (using something like `if word == "": new_word = ""`).

Comment: When you used sentenceEndPunctuation, what was that? I have never seen that before.

Comment: It is just a variable name. I prefer to use more descriptive variable names so I don't forget their purpose.

Comment: What would I use to change the order or the word? Pop and remove won't work because it's a string. For instance "like" would become "ikelay". I need to move the L to the end then add ay.

Comment: Do this in two steps. First, because you already know how to do it, put the first character at the end. So “like” would become “likelay”. I say you already know how to do this because you are already checking the first character of the string: word[0] is the first character (word[1] is the second, word[2] the third, and so on). And you already know how to add a string together: `new_word = word + word[0] + "ay"`.

Comment: Only after you have that first step working, work on the second step: remove the initial consonant from `word`. In Python, you can grab more than one character using square brackets. To get the second character and all subsequent characters, use `word[1:]`, for example. Because [1] means the second character, and the colon means every subsequent character until the end.

Comment: Thanks! I actually figured it out a while ago. You were right, I do have the tools and knowledge to do it:)